# Unable to read botocore.response.StreamingBody due to overflow

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, buffer-overflow, integer-overflow

I am trying to get a file from S3 and read it to python. The object is returned as `botocore.response.Streamingbody`. Usually it can be read using `strmingbody.read()` method. But when I try to use read, it throws a `Overflowerror: Python int too large to convert to C long`.
All the other solutions available in the internet suggests converting `int` to `int64` or `float64`. But I cannot use the `.read()` in the first place due to this error. We even tried to pickle the csv and send, but that also doesn't work.

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd

def get_cx_data():
    """ Get cx data
    Returns:
        Pandas DataFrame: CX index DataFrame
    """    
    client = boto3.client('s3',
                           aws_access_key_id = 'key_id_here',
                           aws_secret_access_key = 'secret_key_here',
                           region_name = 'us-east-2')
    obj = client.get_object(
    Bucket = 'bucket name',
    Key = 'key_here')
    print(type(obj))
    print(obj['Body'])
    file_ = obj['Body'].read()   #throws_overflowerror
    with open('training_data.csv', 'w') as file:
        file.write(obj['Body'].read())   #throws_overflowerror
    # combine_inde_dep_vars_featools.pkl
    
    # Read data from the S3 object
    #data = pandas.read_csv(obj['Body'])
    # df_cx_index = pd.read_pickle("combine_inde_dep_vars_featools.pkl")
    df_cx_index = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()))   #throws_overflowerror
    print(df_cx_index.head())
    return df_cx_index
```

The Traceback is given below

```
<class 'dict'>
<botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x0000027EB0533A60>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/my_folder/git repos/collections_completed_checklist_items/save_csv.py", line 22, in <module>
    get_cx_data()
  File "C:/my_folder/git repos/collections_completed_checklist_items/save_csv.py", line 18, in get_cx_data
    file_ = obj['Body'].read()
  File "C:\CX_codes\environments\collections_completed_checklist_items\lib\site-packages\botocore\response.py", line 77, in read
    chunk = self._raw_stream.read(amt)
  File "C:\CX_codes\environments\collections_completed_checklist_items\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 515, in read
    data = self._fp.read() if not fp_closed else b""
  File "C:\Users\a.mundachal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 468, in read
    s = self._safe_read(self.length)
  File "C:\Users\a.mundachal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 609, in _safe_read
    data = self.fp.read(amt)
  File "C:\Users\a.mundachal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\a.mundachal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Users\a.mundachal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Is there any other way to read or save the `botocore.response.StreamingBody` object as the csv without using `.read()`. Or is there any work around to use the `.read()` without getting `OverflowError`?

Comment: Do you have any reproducible example of data in `training_data.csv`? What in those file that causes the issue?

Comment: The csv contains mostly numerical values and some categorical values for training a machine learning model. It has got 228945 lines of records with 60+ columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_csv('s3://path_to_file/training_data.csv')
```

should work. Install s3fs if not. And make sure your credentials are accessible.

If that doesn't work, try

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s3_root_bucket = 'the_main_bucket_you_start_in'
s3_path_to_file = 'the rest of the path from there to the csv file including the csv filename'

s3_client = boto3.client('s3') #add credentials if necessary

csv_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket = s3_root_bucket, Key = s3_path_to_file)

csv_string = csv_object['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_string))
```